# how do i select last raw in CSV files and import in to Excel?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

How i can select last raw in text files with for?
this my first idea code :

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
path = input("Insert location:")
file_list = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
txt_list = []
for file in file_list:
    txt_list.append(pd.read_csv(file))
    for file in file_list:
        txt_list[-7::3]
excl_merged = pd.concat(txt_list, ignore_index=True)
excl_merged.to_excel('Total.xlsx', index=False) ]
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to grab the last row from every .txt file in that directory, combine them, and load that into Excel?  You don't really need pandas for that.  You can just make a new csv.  Excel reads those just fine.  What is the `[-7::3]` supposed to be doing?

Comment: `[-7::3]` mean select last three data in text file and import into one excel file

Comment: What that actually says is "take the 7th line from the end, the 4th line from the end, and the last line".  But then you throw them away, since you didn't store them anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect. Here is a version that should work:

```py
import glob
import pandas as pd
path = input("Insert location:")
file_list = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
df_list = []
for file in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df_list.append(df.tail(3)) # last 3 rows from each file dataframe
excl_merged = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
excl_merged.to_excel('Total.xlsx', index=False)
```

**Explaination:**  `tail()` method takes the last several rows (provided as an argument) from a dataframe.